# How to play a private match on android?

Tags: dungeon-defenders, android

I want to play with my friend and nobody else. If I make a public game, anyone can join. If I make a private match, however, according to any information I can find online, I have to "alt-tab to Steam, right-click on your friend, and invite to game". Which is great, except I'm on an Android phone. How do I play with my friend under this setup?

To clarify: I can host a game easily. I can join a game easily. But if I host a game that's of type Private Match, I'm alone in the game and can't figure out how to invite anyone else. A search for my username reveals no matches available for my friend to join. We're both on Android systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would seem that this functionality does not work. I can play with people who are not on Android, or I can play a public game, kick everyone else out, and lock it once my friend is in, but I cannot play a private match and then invite a friend like every other system can do. Anyone know how to file a bug report?

Comment: Read my answer again i added info with their feedback/support e-mail and with qouote on how to format the e-mail you will be sending them.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ Wait, that's for IOS. I'm on Android. Is there a feedbackandroid email?

Comment: Not that i know of,this is the only e-mail they provided in their support section.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from steam's FAQ about the matter:

> For servers, you will be able to join and create matches. You can
>   select Quick Match to instantly join a match being hosted by some
>   other player. Custom Match brings you to a list of servers being
>   hosted by other players. From this veiw you will be able to filter
>   your search to things such as specific character lvl’s. **Also
>   from Custom Match you will have the ability to Host your own games.
>   When Hosting your match will appear on the Custom Match list for other
>   players to join. The last option is Private Match. With this you will
>   be able to Host a match that is Invite Only.** In any match type the
>   host has the option to boot any player for any reason.

Also as much as i know you need to have the latest version of the game installed,which i believe is 2.0 at the moment,and with it you can play private matches cross-platform as well.

**Sources:** [Source #1](http://www.poweredbygamespy.com/2011/09/26/dungeon-defenders-cross-platform/) [Source #2](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2184756) [Source #3](http://dungeondefenders.com/tag/android)

**Additional info:**

You can also start the public game with your friend then go to pause menu and use "Lock" option which delists the game and prevents anyone else from joining it,basically making your match private.

**If you can't get it to  work you can send e-mail describing your problem to devs; feedbackios@trendyent.com**

Format for e-mail (quoted from official Dungeon Defenders site on Support section):

> Please start your email with your iOS device and version number and then describe your issue. We will get back to you as soon as possible!

Comment: I have the options listed, but I can't figure out how to send an invite to an Invite Only game. I downloaded the app just last week, so I'd expect I have the latest version. The "Lock" option might be useful in my situation though, but I'd prefer to use the private game functionality so I don't have to be impolite and kick anyone who accidentally joins before I lock the match.

Comment: @Yamikuronue Did you login to gamespy?You can create private game and then tell your friend your gamespy ID and password for the game so he can find you.

Comment: Yes. A search for my username revealed no matches available while I had a private match open.

Comment: @Yamikuronue Well why don't you let your friend make a private game then and join his.I really don't see why it doesn't work for you so i suggest you report that on DD's official forum and hopefully someone there will help you fix the issue.

Comment: Because it doesn't work the other way either. We're both on Android phones and I can't find anything that confirms that a private match created under Android should show up for other players; instead, all I find are statements that indicate it'd be unlisted. As far as I can tell, as designed, I can create a private match but nobody else can ever join.

Comment: @Yamikuronue, can you have friends lists through Gamespy? Because I think that why no one can "see" a private game normally, you have to be invited to it or enter through a friendlist.

Comment: @Gwen I have no idea. It's possible, but I was unable to find such a feature, hence this question :/ I had much the same thought

Comment: Well since there doesn't seem to actually be a way to do this, I've given you the bounty for trying. :|